# why wont pygame work on windows?

Tags: python, installation, windows-installer, pygame, python-3.3

I am using python 3.3 on windows 7 (64-bit) and am using pygame 3.3 (or trying to).

i use the msi installers from the official python website and the pygame msi installers from bit bucket (https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/downloads)

when i finish the install i have tried importing pygame in the python command line, the IDLE (python GUI) and useing a .py file. all of these haven't worked.

i type:

```
import pygame
```

when i do i the IDLE (python GUI) gives me this error message.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3mHN.jpg

i have re installed both python and pygame multiple games and i don't know what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a 64bit python with a 32bit binary install so of course it wouldn't work. Officially there is no 64bit installer for pygame, but [this unofficial version](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame) works just fine.

Comment: You are using pygame on a 64bit machine (with a 64bit python I take it) version 3.3, so you want to download the `pygame-1.9.2a0.win-amd64-py3.3.exe`

Comment: If @yuvi answer helped you to solve the problem you can accept his answer.